# Fetch AWS SSM Parameter using ansible and using aws profile or arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Trying to fetch secrets from another AWS account using ansible. Do we have any option to use I am role arn of the secret aws account to fetch parameters. Because every instance that we are creating will have linked with this secrets AWS accounts ARN.

```
  IAMSECRETARN  : arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/service/xxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-79392xx94110xxxx
```

```
---
- name: Testing shared Roles
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: lookup a key which doesn't exist failing to store it in a fact
    set_fact:
       temp_secret: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/xxx/xxx/xxx/ansible-tower/admin_password' region='us-east-1', aws_profile='xxx-xxx-xxx') }}"
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: SSM PARAMS
    debug:
       msg: "{{ temp_secret }}"
```

Instead of "profile" need to use the "arn" or any other method without secret and access key

Comment: You appear to have omitted what happened when you ran the "below code"; what is your question, exactly?

Comment: I want to use i am role arn in aws_ssm lookup so that i will get the output at first step itself. I don't want to use secret and access keys.

Using the arn role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxxx/xxxxxx" it should work

Answer (score 2):

I DID WITH THE BELOW CODE AS OF NOW:

```
---
- name: ssm parameter
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - sts_assume_role:
      role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxxx/xxxxxx"
      role_session_name: "ssm"
      region: us-east-1
    register: assumed_role
    no_log: true
    
  - name: lookup ssm parameter
    debug: msg="{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/database_password', region='us-east-1', aws_access_key=assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key, aws_secret_key=assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key, aws_security_token=assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token ) }}"
```

Comment: the example can be found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_secret_lookup.html#ansible-collections-amazon-aws-aws-secret-lookup and here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ssm_lookup.html